# Reproduction in animals

Tags: genetics, evolution, reproduction, sexual-reproduction

Humans have acquired knowledge about their environment through many observations. Today, humans have wide variety of resources to gain knowledge about reproduction in human beings and other reproductive processes. This knowledge does not come from genes. But on the other hand the animals example pig don't have any kind of resources which teach them about reproduction, still they can perform their reproductive processes. Even an isolated mice can do so if a mate comes in his vicinity.

**But the isolated mice doesn't have any knowledge about reproduction then how can they perform it?**
https://animals.mom.com/how-a-pig-reproduce-2607021.html

https://oacu.oir.nih.gov/sites/default/files/uploads/training-resources/mouserepro.pdf

Comment: TL;DR: instinct. Even humans don't require any knowledge to reproduce. If you just do together what feels good, there is a good chance that it ends with sex. Behavior of most mammals is much more strongly triggered by pheromones than that of homo sapiens. You probably should start with reading about the [vomeronasal organ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vomeronasal_organ) and the response triggered in rodent brains by reception of sex pheromones.

Comment: Animals don't have any great knowledge about the processes of digestion, yet they manage to eat.  Consider that if animals (or plants, bacteria, &c) had to be taught how to reproduce, and understand all the biological details, they would never manage to reproduce at all :-)

Comment: Arguably, humans, upon learning in detail about reproductive processes and their control, seem to tend toward *avoiding* those processes reaching their biological ends rather than seeking them out.

Answer (score 3):

Instinct

What is [instinct](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5182125/), instinct is any behavior which did not require cognition or consciousness to perform or innate behavior that does not require learning.

BY the nature of building a brain it is possible to build in behavior by laying out neurons and connections in preset patterns. Thus some behavior can be encoded genetically.

Simple examples of Instincts include reflexes and [fixed action patterns](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4684-8306-2_10), but there is a whole spectrum of behaviors ranging from pure instinct to pure learned and everything in between.